# How to link all pages & exclude current page in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I currently have some PHP working exactly as I want it to (generating a list of all pages with the same page template).

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(
    array('meta_key' => '_wp_page_template','meta_value' => 'template.php'));
    foreach($pages as $page){
        echo "<p>$page->post_title</p>";
    }
?>
```

But now I want to do two things.

First - I want each p tag to also have an href, linking to the corresponding page.

Second - I want to exclude the page I am on from being on the list (otherwise it will be linking to the page the viewer is already on, making it repetitive).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `p` elements don’t have a `href` attribute. You want an `a` element inside of your paragraph. _“I want to exclude the page I am on from being on the list”_ - then go research how you find out the ID of the page you are currently on, and then simply exclude it from being output via a simple if-condition around the output in your loop …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise the `WP_Query` class to perform a targeted lookup of almost anything in Wordpress.

In this case, we filter with the `post__not_in` and the `_wp_page_template` meta lookup, before doing the "pages loop". Remember to call `wp_reset_postdata()` at the end of the loop to make it so that the various (get_)the_* functions return data for the current page again:

```php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
    'post__not_in' => array(
        get_the_ID()
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'and',
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'template.php',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
));

if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();

        echo '<p><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!